# Does updating Cordova mean updating node and npm?

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm currently using Cordova CLI version 3.6 with nodejs version 0.10 and npm version 1.4.
If I upgrade Cordova, do I have to upgrade npm and node too?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the Apache Cordova latest doc said:-](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2019/04/11/nodejs-6.x-8.x-deprecation-timeline.html)

> Currently, all of the latest released platforms, tools, and core
>   libraries require a minimum version of node 6.x to be installed.
>   Additionally, we have added support for node 10.x.

As they have Deprecated all of the node version below 6. So you should upgrade both of your "node and npm version", otherwise few lib. functionality aren't going to work.

You are working with very old version, the current stable version of node is **12.13. 1 (2019-11-26)** and you are with **0.10**.

Hope it would help!

Comment: You can use "nvm" or "n" module to update or degrade the node version

Comment: If you wish to install node 10.x and 6.x npm in  Ubuntu linux. Use below commands:-

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
it will install both npm with nodejs